# Property test value is ignored by scalatest

Tags: scala, scalatest, scalacheck

This one is driving me nuts. The following property test passes in scalatest (using "sbt test" target).

```
import org.scalatest.FlatSpec
import org.scalatest.prop.PropertyChecks

class FigaroCheckSpec extends FlatSpec with PropertyChecks {
  "this property" should "fail" in { forAll { (p :Int) => false } }
}
```

Why? I tried both with FlatSpec and with FreeSpec. It also works (that is it fails) when I use Checkers with the scalacheck API directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not have a check/assertion in there, try this:

```
"this property" should "fail" in { forAll { (p :Int) => assert(false) } }
```

Comment: Oh. I see. Very useful to know.  The docs are a bit messy on what are the differences btw the scalacheck and scalatest API.  They almost make an impression that  it is only about using a different forAll.  Thanks! assert appears excessive in a forall, but I guess, if I use matchers it will look sensibly.